# How to convert json to Map<String, Object> making sure integers will be Integer

Tags: java, json, hashmap, integer, double

I have a json object which contains nested objects with values as `String`, `Double` and `Integer`. When I convert to `Map`, its assuming `Integer` as `Double`. How can I change this ?

```
Map<String, Object> map = response.getJson();
```

my response has fields as

```
{
    ....
    "age" : 14,
    "average" : 12.2,
    ....
}
```

`average` is being converted properly into `Double` but age is expected as an `Integer` but being `converted` to `Double` in `Map`

Comment: JSON doesn’t distinguish between integers and floats (and you’re not converting, you’re using whatever conversion are built on to whatever JSON/web/etc library you’re using—*it’s* doing the conversion.

Comment: Why do you care? Also, what if `average` happens to be a whole number? If you apply generic conversion based solely on the value, you might get some `average` values as `Integer`, and some as `Double`. That kind of inconsistency should be avoided!! Which means that *you* need to name which ones should be converted.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have integers. All Numbers in JSON are Doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by post-processing the `Map`, to convert `Double` values to `Integer` where possible, e.g.

```
static void convertIntegerToDouble(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
    for (Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Entry<String, Object> entry = iter.next();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> submap = (Map<String, Object>) value;
            convertIntegerToDouble(submap);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            double d = ((Double) value).doubleValue();
            int i = (int) d;
            if (d == i)
                updates.put(entry.getKey(), i);
        }
    }
    map.putAll(updates);
}
```

*Test*

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
        "A", 42.0,
        "B", new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                "K", 42.0,
                "L", new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                        "R", 42.0,
                        "S", 3.14
                )),
                "M", 3.14
        )),
        "C", 3.14,
        "D", "Foo"
));
System.out.println(map);
convertIntegerToDouble(map);
System.out.println(map);
```

*Output*

```
{A=42.0, B={K=42.0, L={R=42.0, S=3.14}, M=3.14}, C=3.14, D=Foo}
{A=42, B={K=42, L={R=42, S=3.14}, M=3.14}, C=3.14, D=Foo}
```

Comment: Why cast to `Double` after the `instanceof Double` test passes? Why not use `Double::intValue` since you're using `Double::doubleValue`?

Comment: @DavidConrad 1) Since `value` is an `Object`, the cast to `Double` is necessary in order to call `doubleValue()`. 2) [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue--) "returns the value of the `Double` as an `int` after a narrowing primitive conversion", which is what this code is doing too, but the code needs the `double` value too for the `if (d == i)` test, so `doubleValue()` would have to be called even if `intValue()` is used too. This way, there is only one method called on the object.

Comment: @Andreas your solution converts all `Doubles` to `Integers`, I need only one `Double` to be converted as `Integer`

Comment: @Logic Why do you believe it converts all `Doubles` to `Integers`? The test code was specifically written to show that it doesn't, as can be seen in the *output*, where `42.0` (double) was converted to `42` (int), but `3.14` (double) wasn't converted, because it cannot be converted without loss of value, which is the entire point of the `if (d == i)` check in the code.

Comment: @Logic *"I need only one `Double` to be converted"* If you had bothered to respond to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385656/how-to-convert-json-to-mapstring-object-making-sure-integers-will-be-integer/57385999?noredirect=1#comment101255458_57385656) to your question, maybe you might have gotten a better solution that only changed the value of a specifically named property. --- But then again, if the solution is as simple as getting the value of a specifically named property and converting its type, then do you really need to be given such simple code? Do it yourself.